# Ajax requires user to submit information multiple times before it is recived and logged

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm having a little problem getting my data to submit. I'm trying to make a simple chat box using PHP and Ajax, but whenever I try to submit data it will only post after it has been submitted several times. I'm hoping somebody could tell me the problem with me code.

I'm a very novice coder and this is my first time using this site so be nice if its an obvious mistake ^^"

The main chatbox:

```
<head>
<link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendmessage()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

var name=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value);
var message=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("message").value);
xmlhttp.open("POST","insert.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("name="+name+"&message="+message);
}
`</script>`
`</head>`
`<body>`
  `<center>`
    `<table width="600">`
      `<tr>`
        `<td height="400">`
          `<center>`
            `<iframe src ="output.php" width="580px" height="386px">`
              `<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>`
      `</iframe>`
          `</center>`
        `</td>`
      `</tr>`
      `<tr>`
        `<td>`
          `<form method="POST"></br>`
          `&nbsp Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp` 
    `<input type="text" id="name" autocomplete="off" size="15"/><br/><br/>`
    `&nbsp Message: &nbsp`
    `<input type="text" id="message" autocomplete="off"  size="70"/> &nbsp`
    `<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="sendmessage()"/>`
          `</form>`
        `</td>`
      `</tr>`
    `</table>`
  `</center>`
`</body>`

The PHP file which reads the input data and writes it to a log file:

```
<?php
$name='<table><tr><td width="100%">'.$_POST['name']." Says:</td>";
$message="<table><tr><td>".$_POST['message']."</td></tr></table></br>\n"; 
$time="<td>".date("d/m/y-G:i")."</td></tr></table>";
$log = "log.file";
$write = fopen($log, 'a') or die("Can't open file");
fwrite($write, $name);
fwrite($write, $time);
fwrite($write, $message);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: did you try to debug using firebug? Install mozilla's firebug, then put echo statements in the code of the php file which reads the input data, enable console and run the code.

Comment: I'll try that now! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just grabbed your code and tested it out in my computer. Did some small changes but everything if working fine. I just commented

`xmlhttp.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'content');`

then everything worked fine on FireFox.

Below you can see the code that I ran:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendmessage()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


var name=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value);
var message=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("message").value);
xmlhttp.open("POST","insert.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//xmlhttp.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'content');
xmlhttp.send("name="+name+"&message="+message);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <table width="600">
      <tr>
        <td height="400">
          <center>
            <iframe src ="output.php" width="580px" height="386px">
              <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
      </iframe>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <form method="POST"></br>
          &nbsp Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
    <input type="text" id="name" autocomplete="off" size="15"/><br/><br/>
    &nbsp Message: &nbsp
    <input type="text" id="message" autocomplete="off"  size="70"/> &nbsp
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="sendmessage()"/>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
try{
    $name='<table><tr><td width="100%">'.$_POST['name']." Says:</td>";
$message="<table><tr><td>".$_POST['message']."</td></tr></table></br>\n"; 
$time="<td>".date("d/m/y-G:i")."</td></tr></table>";
$file = "output.php";
$write = fopen($file, 'a') or die("Can't open file");
fwrite($write, $name);
fwrite($write, $time);
fwrite($write, $message);
fclose($write);
}catch(Exception $err){
    echo $err; 
}
?>
```

I just tried in FireFox 3.6 Safari 5 and Chrome 6. I'm using a Mac so I didn't tried in IE. In those 3 browsers everything worked fine after the line that I told you at the beginning. Could you proved more details about your problem?

Comment: I knew about that segment of code. It was a previous attempt at fixing the problem I was suffering, but I forgot to remove it when posting this question. The form requires the user to submit the data fields multiple times before it appears to be recognised by the PHP code that should add it to a log file. It doesn't seem to suffer this problem if I don't enter any information into the forms. Sorry about this as it is my first time using the site.

Answer (score 0):

A good measure everyone should adopt is that of security, never explicitly trust your users to be nice and input precisely what you expect them. Always, always check POST and GET variables are safe before using them. Functions such as "strip_tags", "mysql_real_escape" (if you go and place these into a database), should be explored.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've managed to fix the problem. It was as simple as changing the ajax asynchronism to false. Hopefully this should not create any other issued. Thanks guys!